# Codeigniter + S3 - Image upload errors when tring putObject

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

Im wondering if someone could give me a little help.

Im using CodeIgniter for my app .. and im also using the Amazon S3 library here -> https://github.com/psugand/CodeIgniter-S3

Im using the following code to try to upload an image to my S3 account.

```
if ( $this->s3->putObject('filename.jpg', 'profile-images', 'images/filename.jpg, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) ) {
    echo 'Ok';
} else {
    echo 'Fail';
}
```

I am getting the following error back.

```
Message: S3::putObject(): [1] Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Im wondering if anyone has come across this before?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Is this on a local machine or hosted live?
Can you check your <?php phpinfo(); ?> and at the curl section check Protocols to see if https is supported?

Answer (score 0):

Seem that the cURL extension has been compiled without https support. If you are using a hosted server, ask if they can enabled this protocol in cURL, if you are running your own machine, simply recompile cURL with http support or install the appropiate package.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script called info.php and put in it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>.` Save it somewhere on your site so you can access it from a browser.

Find the curl section and check what Protocols are supported. If https is not listed, then cURL was not built with SSL support and you cannot use https.

Now if the curl was not built with the SSL support then if, you are on shared host, request that your host recompile PHP so that both PHP and curl are built with OpenSSL support so you can use encryption, otherwise you will need to find another solution.